# How to replace code easily ? From VBA to Python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, converters

I have 1300 lines of code in VBA who look like this :

```
ElseIf InStr(LCase(A), LCase("B")) Then function = "* C"
```

I want to have something like this in Python :

```
elif (df2["A"]=="B") is True:
        return "* C"
```

Only A, B and C change, do you know any way to do it ? My first idea was to use print and .format to something like this :

```
print("elif (df2['{}']=='{}') is True: return '{}' ".format(A, "B", "* C"))
```

But that's not works to modify hundreds of lines

Comment: Seems like your code needs refactored: 1300 lines is quite a code smell.

Comment: You're probably right but it's only else if condition with variable information and i don't really know how to refactor so it's quite complicated

Answer (score 0):

If someone wonder one day. I have no doubt it exists a better way but at least it works :

```
import re
import csv
a = " "
compteur = 0
second_compteur, first_compteur = "", ""

with open(r"patch") as csvfile:
    liste1 = []
    for row in csvfile:
        a += row

        b = re.compile('"[^"]*"')

        for value in b.findall(a):
            if compteur % 2 == 0:
                first_compteur = value
            else:
                second_compteur = value
            compteur += 1

        with open(r"path_new_csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile2:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile2, quotechar="'")
            writer.writerow(["elif (df2[{}]=={}) is True: return {}".format("ShortDescr", first_compteur, second_compteur)])
```